# Group row data from a 2d array by one column and sum another column per group then find the group with the highest total

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I'm trying to combine the scores of employee for my program. My sample is one employee is evaluated more than one. So basically, if employee 1 have scored of 87 and 90 the total should be 177. After computation, I need to return the result with the highest score.
Here so far my sample code (I simplified my code for this question because it is too long to post the original code):

```
$scores = array( 
    array(1, "allan", 90),
    array(2, "allan", 85),
    array(3, "mark", 100),
    array(4, "jason", 88),
    array(5, "allan", 92),
    array(6, "mark", 77),
    array(7, "mark", 88),
    array(8, "jason", 90)
); 

print_r($scores);

get_topemployee($scores); 

function get_topemployee($scores) {
    $total_score = 0;
    $combined_score = array();

    foreach($scores as $key) {
        for($i=0; count($scores) <= $i; $i++) {
            if($key[0] == $key[0][$i]) {
                $total_score += $key[1];
            }
            $combined_score[] = array($key[0], $key[1], $total_score);
        }
    }

    $employee = ""; // employee with highest score
    $compare_score = 0;
    foreach($combined_score as $value) {
        $compare_score = $value[1];
        if($value[1] >= $compare_score) {
            $employee = $value[0];
        }
    }

    return $employee;
}
```

The result does not return the employee with highest score and not sure which in my code is incorrect. thanks for help

do this:- https://3v4l.org/WhVaN

Comment: array with 2 identical keys? doesn't make sense... you can have 2 element with key "mark" in `$scores`

Comment: @dWinder assuming that we have unique id on each element since it's for evaluation

Comment: same indexes in a single-dimensional array will get replaced. check here:- https://3v4l.org/LOgUZ

Comment: So please change your input data as for now it is not valid

Comment: `$scores.length` - this is javascript, not php.

Comment: @jned29  please change your input array and let us show the expected outcome format also

Comment: I have updated the sample array above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to convert your scores array into an array of total scores indexed by employee:

```
$scores = array_reduce($scores, function ($c, $v) { 
    $name = $v[1];
    if (isset($c[$name])) {
        $c[$name] += $v[2];
    }
    else {
        $c[$name] = $v[2];
    }
    return $c;
}, array());
```

You can then use [`arsort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) to sort the array in reverse order while maintaining the key association. You can then use [`key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) to get the key of the first element, which will be the name of the employee with the highest score:

```
arsort($scores);
echo key($scores);
```

Output:

```
allan
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rZ4SY)

To print out all the scores, you can simply `print_r($scores)`:

```
Array (
  [allan] => 267
  [mark] => 265
  [jason] => 178 
)
```

Alternatively to print just the highest score, change `echo key($scores);` to `echo key($scores) . ' ' . current($scores);`:

```
allan 267
```

[Updated demo](https://3v4l.org/mTm09).

Comment: @jned29 I've updated my answer based on the changes to your question

Comment: could you also print the total score on each element?

Comment: @jned29 do you mean for the highest score or all of them?

Comment: the total score per each employee like allan => 267

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($scores as $e) {
    if (!isset($res[$e[1]])) $res[$e[1]] = 0;
    $res[$e[1]] += $e[2]; 
}
print_r(array_keys($res, max($res)));
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/VErjs)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet for you, please see inline doc for explanation

```
$result = [];
array_walk($scores, function($item) use(&$result){
   // pushing on the behalf of name and checking if not isset with '??'
   $result[$item[1]] = ($result[$item[1]] ?? 0) + $item[2]; 
});
// searching for index with max value in result and show max value too 
echo array_search(max($result), $result).' -> '. max($result);
```

[array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

**Output**

```
allan -> 267
```

[**Demo Link**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbf027c146288bbc0040f4935d0d73713e453324).

Answer (score 1):

```
$scores = [
    [1, 'allan', 90],
    [2, 'allan', 85],
    [3, 'mark', 100],
    [4, 'jason', 88],
    [5, 'allan', 92],
    [6, 'mark', 77],
    [7, 'mark', 88],
    [8, 'jason', 90]
];

function maxScore(array $scores): string {
    $preparedScores = [];

    foreach ($scores as $score) {
        $key   = $score[1];
        $value = $score[2];

        if (isset($preparedScores[$key])) {
            $preparedScores[$key] += $value;
        } else {
            $preparedScores[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    arsort($preparedScores);

    return array_key_first($preparedScores);
}

echo maxScore($scores);
```

**Result:**

```
allan
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scores = array( 
    array(1, "allan", 90),
    array(2, "allan", 85),
    array(3, "mark", 100),
    array(4, "jason", 88),
    array(5, "allan", 92),
    array(6, "mark", 77),
    array(7, "mark", 88),
    array(8, "jason", 90)
); 


get_topemployee($scores); 

function get_topemployee($scores) {
    $total_score = 0;
    $combined_score = array();

    $highest_score = 0;
    $highest_employee = '';

    foreach($scores as $key => $value) {
        if ( ! isset($combined_score[$value[1]])) {
            $combined_score[$value[1]] = $value[2];
        }
        else {
            $combined_score[$value[1]] += $value[2];
        }

        if ($highest_score < $combined_score[$value[1]]) {
            $highest_score = $combined_score[$value[1]];
            $highest_employee = $value[1];  //the highest value employee
        }   
    }

    return $highest_employee;
}
```